# SVG.js size method not working after upgrade from v2.7 to v3.1

Tags: svg.js

I was using v2.7 of SVG.js and creating an svg object like this:

```
let svg = SVG('drawing')
    .size(inputs.overallWidth * scale, inputs.overallHeight * scale)
    .viewbox(-0.5, -0.5, inputs.overallWidth + 10, inputs.overallHeight + 10)
    .attr({
        "vector-effect": "non-scaling-stroke",
        "shape-rendering": "geometricPrecision"
    });
```

However, I tried to upgrade to v3.1 and when I load the page I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'size'....
```

What's happened to the size() property and what do I replace it with?

Comment: svg.js v3 has breaking changes. pls consolut the docs for a getting started. e.g. it is now `SVG().addTo('#drawing')`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick